# Matriz com camadas alfabéticas Python

Tags: python, matriz, for, while

Estou tentando fazer uma matriz em Python semelhante a este,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas meu código

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esta trazendo o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import string

def exibir_matriz(matriz):
    for linha in matriz:
        print(linha)

camadas = int(input("Quantas camadas: "))

m = camadas+(camadas+1)

n = m

matriz = []
for i in range(m):
    linha = []
    for j in range(n):
        elemento = string.ascii_uppercase[:1]
        linha.append(elemento)
    matriz.append(linha)
matriz[camadas][camadas] = "*"


exibir_matriz(matriz)
```

Já tentei adicionar um `while` ou `for`, mas só consegui chegar ate aqui.

Comment: import string

def exibir_matriz(matriz):
    for linha in matriz:
        print(linha)

camadas = int(input("Quantas camadas: "))

m = camadas+(camadas+1)

matriz = []
for i in range(m):
    linha = []
    for j in range(m):
        elemento = string.ascii_uppercase[:1]
        if i == 0 or i == m-1 or j == 0 or j == m-1:
            linha.append(elemento)
        else:
            linha.append('B')
    matriz.append(linha)
matriz[camadas][camadas] = "*"


exibir_matriz(matriz)

Comment: consegui a camada A e B mas a C ainda não

Answer (score 3):

Tenho outra ideia de construção desse matriz, apenas compartilhando a minha ideia:

```
def exibir_matriz(n):
    Alfabeto = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
    camadas = []
    camada_temp = []
    n_alfa = 2 * n + 1

    for i in range(n):
        camada_temp.insert(i, Alfabeto[i])
        camada_temp.insert(-i, Alfabeto[i])
        c = camada_temp.copy()
        while len(c) < n_alfa:
            c.insert(i, Alfabeto[i])
        camadas.append(c)

    meio = camadas[n-1].copy()
    meio.pop(n)
    meio.insert(n, '*')

    for camada in camadas:
        print(camada)
    print(meio)
    camadas.reverse()
    for camada in camadas:
        print(camada)
```

A ideia é que quando a Matriz tem 3 camadas ele tem 4 tipos de camadas:

```
1 A A A A A A A *tipo1*
2 A B B B B B A *tipo2*
3 A B C C C B A *tipo3*
4 A B C * C B A *tipo4*
5 A B C C C B A *tipo3*
6 A B B B B B A *tipo2*
7 A A A A A A A *tipo1*
```

Temos alguns padrões:

- A maioria dos itens são utilizados 2 vezes.
- A camada do meio é utilizado apenas 1 vez.
- Número de Alfabetos é igual número de camadas, Por exemplo: 3 camadas
  tem A, B, C
- Número de letras por camada é igual `2 * camadas + 1`
- Primeira e a última camada sempre serão apenas A
- Se enumeramos cada letra: 1-A, 2-B, 3-C. O número da letra é igual o número do indíce onde vai começar a letra da camada do mesmo número:

[image: Exemplo]

- A camada é igual a camada anterior só que substituindo o meio, e deixando a pontas com 1 de cada letra existente:

[image: Exemplo]

---

Com esse padrões podemos criar os 4 tipos de camadas, começando com as camadas que duplicam (*tipo1, tipo2, tipo3*):

Primeiro é começar a enumerar os Alfabetos, Definir número de letras por camada e uma *list* de todos os tipos de camadas:

```
n_alfa = 2 * n + 1
Alfabeto =['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
camadas = []
```

Então `Alfabeto[0] = A`, `Alfabeto[1] = B` e assim por diante.

A ideia de montar todos tipos de camadas é usar uma template de *list*.

Para criar essa template, podemos notar que inserimos a letra no mesmo número da índice do número da letra:

```
#1- A
A _ _ _ _ _ A
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

#2- B
A B _ _ _ B A
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Para inserir no fim apenas utilizamos número negativo da *list*:

```
#1- A
A _ _ _ _ _ A
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 (*index* negativo)

#2- B
A B _ _ _ B A
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 (*index* negativo)
```

E preencher ela com a letra de acordo com o número da camada:

```
#Camada 1
camada_temp = ['A','A']
#A _ _ _ _ _ A
#Preencher o meio com letra 'A' (Como disse antes 1-A)

#Camada 2
camada_temp = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
#A B _ _ _ B A
# Preencher o meio com letra 'B' (2-B)
```

E por fim adicionamos esse tipo de camada na *list* de camadas.

```
camada_temp = []

for i in range(n):
    camada_temp.insert(i, Alfabeto[i])  #Inserindo Alfabeto no index positivo
    camada_temp.insert(-i, Alfabeto[i]) #Inserindo Alfabeto no index negativo
    c = camada_temp.copy()              #Duplicando a camada

    while len(c) < n_alfa:              #Preenchendo o meio
        c.insert(i, Alfabeto[i])
    camadas.append(c)                   #Adicionando a 'list' de camadas
```

---

Agora a camada do meio é igual a último tipo de camada só que substituindo o meio.

[image: Exemplo]

O meio é após o número de camadas.

```
A B C C C B A
A B C * C B A
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

```
meio = camadas[n-1].copy()
meio.pop(n)
meio.insert(n, '*')
```

---

Agora só falta montar a matriz, como criamos de camada 1 a 3 podemos imprimir ordenadamente. Depois o meio e depois imprimimos reversamente. A ordem fica:

`1 2 3 meio 3 2 1`

```
for camada in camadas:    #Imprimindo Ordenadamente
    print(camada)

print(meio)               #Meio

camadas.reverse()         #Revertendo a lista

for camada in camadas:    #Imprimindo a lista revertida
    print(camada)
```

---

Colocando *input*:

```
n = input('Numero de camadas...')
exibir_matriz(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

A ideia geral é primeiro entender a estrutura geral da matriz para diferentes tamanhos, e tentar abstrair uma regra que sirva para qualquer tamanho. Por exemplo, para os tamanhos 2 e 3, temos:

```
# 2 camadas
A A A A A  0
A B B B A  1
A B * B A  2
A B B B A  3
A A A A A  4

# 3 camadas
A A A A A A A  0
A B B B B B A  1
A B C C C B A  2
A B C * C B A  3
A B C C C B A  4
A B B B B B A  5
A A A A A A A  6
```

Na última coluna coloquei os índices das linhas.

Repare que na primeira linha (índice zero) só tem a letra "A" (apenas uma letra). Na segunda linha, tem "A" e "B" (duas letras) e assim por diante, até chegar na linha do meio (quando o índice é igual à quantidade de camadas), que terá o asterisco. E depois que passo do meio, a quantidade de letras vai diminuindo, até que chegue na última, que tem somente o "A". A partir daí dá para generalizar um cálculo da quantidade de letras, de acordo com o número da linha.

Depois, em cada linha, começo com "A" e vou avançando até a letra final (que pode ser o próprio "A" na primeira linha, o "B" na segunda, etc), imprimindo cada letra apenas uma vez, exceto pela letra final, que se repete determinado número de vezes (seria o tamanho da matriz menos as demais letras que já foram impressas).

Sendo assim, a generalização ficaria:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase

def montar_matriz(camadas):
    tamanho = 2 * camadas + 1 # tamanho do quadrado
    matriz = []
    for linha in range(tamanho):
        nova_linha = [] # cria uma nova linha da matriz
        # verifica até que letra deve ter nesta linha (ex: se for 3, deve ter A, B e C na linha)
        if linha <= camadas:
            qtd_letras_linha = linha + 1
        else: # na metade de baixo, o cálculo é um pouquinho mais chato
            qtd_letras_linha = linha % camadas
            if qtd_letras_linha == 0:
                qtd_letras_linha = 1
            else:
                qtd_letras_linha = camadas - qtd_letras_linha + 1

        meio = linha == camadas # estou no meio?
        # primeiro avança N letras, começando pelo "A"
        n = qtd_letras_linha - (2 if meio else 1)
        for j in range(n):
            nova_linha.append(ascii_uppercase[j])
        letra = ascii_uppercase[camadas - 1] # letra final
        # estou no meio, imprime "letra * letra"
        if meio:
            nova_linha.extend([letra, '*', letra])
            n -= 1
        else:
            # mostra a letra X vezes (X é o tamanho da linha menos a quantidade de letras que foi impressa apenas uma vez)
            x = tamanho - (2 * qtd_letras_linha) + 1
            nova_linha.extend([ascii_uppercase[qtd_letras_linha - 1]] * x)
        # mostra as mesmas N letras do primeiro for, mas ao contrário, até terminar no "A"
        for j in range(n, -1, -1):
            nova_linha.append(ascii_uppercase[j])
        # adiciona a linha na matriz
        matriz.append(nova_linha)

    return matriz

def mostrar_matriz(m):
    for linha in m:
        print(' '.join(linha))
```

Testando para diferentes tamanhos:

```py
for i in range(1, 7):
    print(f'\n{i} camadas:')
    mostrar_matriz(montar_matriz(i))
```

Saída:

```
1 camadas:
A A A
A * A
A A A

2 camadas:
A A A A A
A B B B A
A B * B A
A B B B A
A A A A A

3 camadas:
A A A A A A A
A B B B B B A
A B C C C B A
A B C * C B A
A B C C C B A
A B B B B B A
A A A A A A A

4 camadas:
A A A A A A A A A
A B B B B B B B A
A B C C C C C B A
A B C D D D C B A
A B C D * D C B A
A B C D D D C B A
A B C C C C C B A
A B B B B B B B A
A A A A A A A A A

5 camadas:
A A A A A A A A A A A
A B B B B B B B B B A
A B C C C C C C C B A
A B C D D D D D C B A
A B C D E E E D C B A
A B C D E * E D C B A
A B C D E E E D C B A
A B C D D D D D C B A
A B C C C C C C C B A
A B B B B B B B B B A
A A A A A A A A A A A

6 camadas:
A A A A A A A A A A A A A
A B B B B B B B B B B B A
A B C C C C C C C C C B A
A B C D D D D D D D C B A
A B C D E E E E E D C B A
A B C D E F F F E D C B A
A B C D E F * F E D C B A
A B C D E F F F E D C B A
A B C D E E E E E D C B A
A B C D D D D D D D C B A
A B C C C C C C C C C B A
A B B B B B B B B B B B A
A A A A A A A A A A A A A
```

Comment: parabens! não reparei esse padrão de lógica.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas complementando a resposta dos demais já satisfatória, minha proposta foi construir a matriz de dentro para fora utilizando uma função recursiva desta forma:

```
import string

def constroi_matriz(matriz, camada_indice, CAMADAS):

  def preenche_linhas_intermediarias():
    for linha in matriz:
      matriz_nova.append([letra, *linha, letra])

  letra = string.ascii_uppercase[CAMADAS - camada_indice]

  linha_constante = [letra] * ((camada_indice * 2) + 1)
  matriz_nova = [linha_constante]

  preenche_linhas_intermediarias()

  matriz_nova.append(linha_constante)

  if camada_indice == CAMADAS:
    return matriz_nova

  return constroi_matriz(matriz_nova, camada_indice + 1, CAMADAS)

def exibir_matriz(camadas):
  for linha in constroi_matriz([['*']], 1, camadas):
    print(' '.join(linha))

exibir_matriz(camadas=int(input("Quantas camadas: ")))
```

EDIT: Conforme solicitado, esclarecendo o código proposto parte por parte:

1. Chama-se a função `constroi_matriz` a partir da função `exibe_matriz` usando como argumento `matriz` inicial uma lista aninhada com valor `'*'` ("raiz" da matriz) — de forma a padronizar o comportamento das chamadas recursivas subsequentes — bem como o valor constante do número de `camadas`

```
def exibir_matriz(camadas):
  ...
  constroi_matriz([['*']], 1, camadas)
  ...
exibir_matriz(camadas=int(input("Quantas camadas: ")))
```

2. Define-se a variável `linha_constante` para representar a primeira e última linhas de cada camada adicionada à matriz (a cada chamada de `constroi_matriz`) e a mesma é atribuída à variável `matriz_nova`

```
linha_constante = [letra] * ((camada_indice * 2) + 1)
matriz_nova = [linha_constante]
...
matriz_nova.append(linha_constante)
```

3. Itera-se a variável `matriz` passada a cada chamada da função `constroi_matriz` em que linha seria o número de linhas da matriz — começando com a "raiz" `['*']` — e a cada uma dessas linhas é adicionado ao começo e final a `letra` correspondente à nova camada

```
def preenche_linhas_intermediarias():
  for linha in matriz:
    matriz_nova.append([letra, *linha, letra])
...
preenche_linhas_intermediarias()
```

4. Retorna-se a variável `matriz_nova` quando a `camada_indice` (ponteiro referente à camada corrente, em formação) for igual ao número de `camadas` definida inicialmente, encerrando-se a recursão; caso contrário, a matriz modificada é reintroduzida à rotina da função `constroi_matriz`

```
if camada_indice == CAMADAS:
  return matriz_nova

return constroi_matriz(matriz_nova, camada_indice + 1, CAMADAS)
```

5. Baseando-se na implementação de @hkotsubo, itera-se sobre as listas aninhadas (linhas da matriz), que são escritas individualmente com cada uma das letras separadas por espaço

```
for linha in constroi_matriz([['*']], 1, camadas):
  print(' '.join(linha))
```

Finalmente, o resultado da execução tomando como referência a pergunta original com `CAMADAS = 3`:

```
>>> exibir_matriz(camadas=3)
A A A A A A A
A B B B B B A
A B C C C B A
A B C * C B A
A B C C C B A
A B B B B B A
A A A A A A A
```

EDIT 2:

### Python 3 (>= 3.5.0)

```
def constroi_matriz(matriz, camada_indice, CAMADAS):

  def preenche_linhas_intermediarias():
    for linha in matriz:
      matriz_nova.append([letra, *linha, letra])
```

### Python 2 / 3 (< 3.5.0)

```
def constroi_matriz(matriz, camada_indice, CAMADAS):

  def preenche_linhas_intermediarias():
    for linha in matriz:
      linha_lista = [letra]
      linha_lista.extend(linha)
      linha_lista.append(letra)

      matriz_nova.append(linha_lista)
```

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor o funcionamento?

Comment: @Danizavtz Detalhamento adicionado, se ainda estiver insuficiente fico à disposição para quaisquer esclarecimento e/ou revisão.

Comment: Deu certo eu que digitei errado: https://ideone.com/D4YfYB